# Returning synchronous message from service, but then doing asynchronous processing - concern about hanging threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, service

Essentially I've written a service in Java that will do initial synchronous processing (a couple simple calls to other web services).  Then, after that processing is done, I return an acknowledgement message to the caller, saying I've verified their request and there is now downstream processing happening in the background asynchronously.

In a nutshell, what I'm concerned about is the complexity of the async processing.  The sum of those async calls can take up to 2-3 minutes depending on certain parameters sent.  My thought here is: what if there's a lot of traffic at once hitting my service, and there are a bunch of hanging threads in the background, doing a large chunk of processing.  Will there be bad data as a result? (like one request getting mixed in with a previous request etc)

The code follows this structure:

1. Validation of headers and params in body
2. Synchronous processing
3. Return acknowledgement message to the caller
4. Asynchronous processing

For #4, I've simply made a new thread and call a method that does all the async processing within it.  Like:

```
new Thread()
      {
        @Override
          public void run()
          {
            try {
            makeDownstreamCalls(arg1, arg2 , arg3, arg4);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          }
        }.start();
```

I'm basically wondering about unintended consequences of lots of traffic hitting my service.  An example I'm thinking about: a thread executing downstream calls for request A, and then another request comes in, and a new thread has to be made to execute downstream calls for request B.  How is request B handled in this situation, and what happens to request A, which is still in-progress?   Will the async calls in request A just terminate in this case?  Or can each distinct request, and thread, execute in parallel just fine and complete, without any strange consequences?

Comment: If you're creating a new thread for each call for the asynchronous processing, one consequence would be that your server would probably grind to a halt and crash when encountering lots of traffic. Problems depend on whether there can be concurrency issues between those requests, and how well your code handles those issues.

Comment: What are some general approaches to dealing with those kinds of crashes?  There shouldn't be a TON of action at once for these requests, but it's reasonable expect that some requests are sent within a minute of each other.

Comment: Well you don't really want to create a new thread every time you want to perform a task on the background. That's amateur code. A suitably sized threadpool on the other hand will ensure that you're not creating too many threads, but there are enough threads to keep things going.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer depends on your code, of which you posted a small part, so my answer contains some guesswork. I'll assume that we're talking about some sort of multi-threaded server which accepts client requests, and that those request come to some `handleRequest()` method which performs the 4 steps you've mentioned. I'll also assume that the requests aren't related in any way and don't affect each other (so for instance, the code **doesn't** do something like "if a thread already exists from a previous request then don't create a new thread" or anything like that).

If that's the case, then your `handleRequest()` method can be simultaneously invoked by different server threads concurrently. And each will execute the four steps you've outlined. If two requests happen simultaneously, then a server thread will execute your handler for request A, and a different one will execute it for B at the same time. If during the processing of a request, a new thread is created, then one will be created for A, another for B. That way, you'll end up with two threads performing `makeDownstreamCalls()`, one with A's parameters one with B's.

In practice, that's probably a pretty bad idea. The more threads your program will create, the more context-switching the OS has to do. You really don't want the number of requests to increase the number of threads in your application endlessly. Modern OSes are capable of handling hundreds or even thousands of threads (as long as they're bound by IO, not CPU), but it comes at a cost. You might want to consider using a Java [executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) with a limited number of threads to avoid crushing your process or even OS.

If there's too much load on a server, you can't expect your application to handle it. Process what you can within the limit of the application, and reject further request. Accepting more requests when you're fully loaded means that your application crashes, and none of the requests are processed - this is known as "Load Shedding".

Comment: Thank you for the insight here.

In light of your comments, I quickly put this together:

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
            Runnable runnableTask = () -> {
              try {
                makeDownstreamCalls(args);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            };
            executor.execute(runnableTask);

What are the consequences of this approach?  My service cannot execute >10 requests concurrently?  If there's an 11th req, it enters into a queue waiting to be grabbed?

Comment: Yeah, the 11th request will be placed into a queue. If there are too many requests, the queue will grow and eventually end up causing an OutOfMemoryError